# Konsole terminal showing tearing when running commands

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, intel-graphics, tearing, konsole

I'm getting this weird "screen tearing" kind of effect when running commands on my terminal The tearing actually shows what's behind the terminal, in this case I had youtube on Firefox behind the Konsole.

This is only showing when hitting enter to execute a command. Tearing seems to disappear when minimizing and maximizing the window again, running clear or even by just hitting enter multiple times. This is the only application showing this behavior.

Any ideas on a fix? I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 on a HP Envy x360 running on a 8th gen Intel core, no Nvidia or AMD dedicated graphics card.

[image: image showing the tearing effect on Konsole application]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this issue on Kubuntu 18.10, I solved it by resetting my screen scaling value to 1 in System settings > Display and monitor > Scale Display

Comment: I'm so sorry I totaly forgot about this since I just gave up back when I was facing this issue, I can confirm however that almost a year and a half later (Just tried this in Kubuntu 20.04), this does fix the issue although it leaves you with a unusable display if using a retina screen since most of the time you really need the scaling factor to be higher.